# Using light effect (brightness) in qml

Tags: qt, qml, brightness

I'm trying to make a light effect that appears from my image whenever i click on it, i have tried the following:

```
     Image {
             id: image1
             source: "../../blue_dot.png"


     BrightnessContrast {
               id:myBright
               x: image1.width/2
               y: image1.height/2
               visible: false
             }


     MouseArea{
               anchors.fill: parent

               onPressed: {
                 myBright.brightness = 1
                 myBright.visible = true
                          }
             }

         }
```

but unfortunately nothing appears whenever i click on my image, Any ideas on how can i make a light effect out of an image using qml?

Comment: `BrightnessContrast` changes the luminance. Do you want to achieve a sort of "turned on"/"turned off" effect? If that is the case, what do you think about [`Glow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-glow.html) effect?

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way to use a GraphicalEffect. Have a look a the official [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-brightnesscontrast.html).

You have to :

- Set the visibility of your image to false and the visibility of the effect to true
- Set the width and height of the graphical effect to the height and width of the image (`anchors.fill: image` is fine)
- Set the source property of the graphicalEffect to your image's id
- OnClicked, ajust the contrast/brightness properties of the GraphicalEffect (default: 0, 0)

Someting like this:

```
Image {
    id: image1
    source: "../../blue_dot.png"
    visible: false
}
BrightnessContrast {
    id:myBright
    anchors.fill: image1
    source: image1
}

MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPressed: {
        myBright.brightness==0? myBright.brightness= 0.2:myBright.brightness=0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that some required properties are not set:

```
BrightnessContrast {
               id:myBright
               x: image1.width/2
               y: image1.height/2
               visible: false
               // New properties:
               source: image1
               width: 100
               height: 100

             }
```

Width and height I choose randomly. You should replace my values with correct ones. But mb better will be to use something like "anchors.fill: image1".